# sbt ignore test failures

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, sonarqube

For SonarQube jobs in Jenkins we'd like to proceed even though some tests might fail. Currently the Sonar Runner is not kicked off, because a test fails.
In Maven you'd just add `-DtestFailureIgnore = true`, but I cannot find anything similar for SBT.

I did find a `onFailure` thing for sbt, but have not found any examples anywhere how to use this. Could this be used to ignore test failures so the build job continues so the Sonar Runner gets started afterwards?

Or is there a setting in Jenkins to ignore the result of the build?
We use 'sbt clean coverage test coverageReport' as build command and have Sonar Runner in a post-build step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found a solution myself.

In SBT you can define a new task A which captures the result of another task B. This dependency ensures that task B is run when the new task A is started. By capturing the result, the result of task B is not the result of task A so if B fails, A does not (have to) fail.

So in this case, I added created a new 'ciTests' tasks to the 'build.sbt'

```
// Define a special test task which does not fail when any test fails,
// so sequential tasks (like SonarQube analysis) will be performed no matter the test result.
lazy val ciTests = taskKey[Unit]("Run tests for CI")

ciTests := {
  // Capture the test result
 val testResult = (test in Test).result.value
}
```

Now in the Jenkins job it build the project using SBT with commands (using [SCoverage SBT plugin](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage)):

```
update coverage ciTests coverageReport
```

This build will succeed ignoring any failing tests. Therefore a next build step to start SonarRunner will start the analysis of the Scala project and put the results in SonarQube.

Thanks to @hugo-zwaal for pointing me to [this answer](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/simple-build-tool/137403rx6x/sbt-sbt-exit-code#20130708s5zurm52nl5kda7lxq7hjdozrq) which helped me solving my issue.